# Can an object have properties which its prototype doesn't have?

Tags: javascript, prototype

In JavaScript, must an object and its prototype (i.e. its property `prototype` as an object) have exactly the same set of properties?

Can an object have properties which its prototype doesn't have?

Comment: Nop, but it's more related to good practices.

Comment: @Reflective How so? The ability for an instance to deviate from its prototype is a central feature of prototypical inheritance.

Comment: The question " ... have exactly the same set of properties? " - Answer - no, they may have extra properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In JavaScript, must an object and its prototype (i.e. its property
>   prototype as an object) have exactly the same set of properties?

**No.** The `prototype` is used to create instances of objects. At the moment an instance is created, the instance becomes a separate object from the prototype and modifications to it don't affect the prototype (however, changes to the prototype will affect the instance). Welcome to [prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)!

> Can an object have properties which its prototype doesn't have?

**Yes**, here's an example:

```js
function foo(){
  // doesn't matter what it does
}

let fooInstance = new foo();

console.log(foo.prototype.bar); // undefined
console.log(fooInstance.bar);   // undefined
console.log("************************");

// Give the instance object a new property.
// This does not create a property on the instance's prototype
fooInstance.bar = "baz";

console.log(foo.prototype.bar); // undefined
console.log(fooInstance.bar);   // baz
console.log("************************");

console.log(foo.prototype.hasOwnProperty("bar"));  // false
console.log(fooInstance.hasOwnProperty("bar"));    // true
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes or no?

Comment: As the first word of my answer states, no.

Comment: Which question do you say no/yes to: "must an object and its prototype (i.e. its property prototype as an object) have exactly the same set of properties?" and "Can an object have properties which its prototype doesn't have?"

Comment: I've updated my answer for clarity, but if the first answer is "No", then that implies the answer to your second question is "yes". Additionally, my code example shows these answers clearly.

Comment: The example clearly shows the answer :) and you can add methods as well as properties too.

Comment: @Reflective Technically, JavaScript doesn't have methods - - it's a functional language. Functions are data. So when you create a "method", all you are really doing is creating a property that stores a function. If you were to access the property, you would see the function's code. When you add `()` on to the end of the retrieved property, you are saying you wish to invoke the code that was retrieved from the property.

Comment: Well, the thing you just described is usually called "method" :) I clearly understand what you are meaning, that in Javascript methods are defined as properties containing function data - yes - absolutely ... which also mean that you can redefine a method at each point. But strictly there's no term 'method' in Javascript, but how do you call function properties in Javascript?

Comment: @Reflective I feel it's important to draw the distinction here at Stack Overflow because we're not just answering a single question from a single person, we're adding to a knowledge base that others will come across for years to come. The more specific we can be (especially for newbies), the less misconceptions and misunderstandings people will have along their learning paths. JavaScript objects can implement behaviors (similar to traditional OOP methods in class based languages), but there is a difference. There really is no first-class method feature as there is in many other languages.

Comment: *how do you call function properties in Javascript* You use the invocation operator `()`.

Comment: So you are usually telling "I'll call this property with the invocation operator" ... strictly - absolutely correct - but practically I've never heard that way of talking :) Object is a part of OO conscept, so we may use the OO term saying "method". Methods have very different way of implementation in the different languages so there's no such thing as "pure method"  except in the OO concept in general.

Comment: You may use the term "method". I didn't say you couldn't. But since the question was related to how properties work, I thought it important to clarify the details based on your initial comment about methods. But, you are incorrect about there only being a "general" concept of the method. In languages like Java, C++, and C#, you use different syntax to define a method than to define a property and that syntax difference causes the code to compile down to fundamentally different instructions for properties vs. methods. (cont)

Comment: This is part of what it means for functions to be considered a ["first-class citizen"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function) in JavaScript - - they are just data. Methods are not first-class citizens in JavaScript because, there isn't really any such thing. But there are in other languages.

Comment: Do you know how methods are implemented in Perl per instance? :) As I previously told `strictly` your state is absolutely right. No doubt about it :)

Answer (score 1):

I case you have to stick to the prototype you may `seal()` the object. 
The `Object.seal()` method seals an object, preventing new properties from being added to it and marking all existing properties as non-configurable. Values of present properties can still be changed as long as they are writable.

[Object.seal() MDN definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)

You can also `freeze()` an Object, but this will prevent changing any part of the object.

Comment: But, you can always use a frozen or sealed object as the prototype for another one and then add additional properties to the new one. ;)

Comment: You are able to seal any instance. As you already said, an instantiated Object in JavaScript lives itsown life. But you have the choice to protect it or not. Depending on your idea and application you may protect an object or give it a chance to be `free` (for a change).

Comment: Keep in mind that in the case you described you have a new instance so the instance used as prototype is neighter equal (==)  nor identical (===) to the the new instance based on the sealed instance (used as prototype).

Comment: Of course. I was just illustrating how flexible objects are in JavaScript.